# jQuery validate not working on IE10 compatibility mode

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-8, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I am using jQuery validate to perform the validation on my form. I am currently using 1.11.1 version which is the latest as of this writing. This works fine in IE10, IE9, IE8, IE7 and chrome. However, if I use IE10 and choose document mode IE8, it doesn't work. It always returns true and the form is submitted.

Does anyone know of any work around?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: no errors. it just submits the form even if validation should fail.

Comment: checkout my question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080731/jquery-validate-bug-with-required-validation-on-ie10-in-compatibility-mode-to-ie it relates to a different bug at IE10 compatibility view but i had the same symptom and it went away after my fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with IE10 in compatibility mode to IE8 = it returns an empty string even if ah attribute doesn't exist so

```
 $(event.target).attr("formnovalidate") !== undefined
```

is always true and the validation is skipped
forked the jQuery validation plugin and fixed it,
here is the fix: https://github.com/avipinto/jquery-validation/commit/efd7daf95eb5ed4acf44cd5523e0a23ab88c2a9d