# jQuery validate bug with required validation on IE10 in compatibility mode to IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery-validate, internet-explorer-10, ie8-compatibility-mode

there is a [Confirmed bug in IE10 compatibility mode](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/449ca2d0-038f-4c1d-b926-9b499106242c/internet-explorer-10-changing-required-attribute-in-compatibility-mode) that won't be fixed for IE10:

**In IE10 in compatibility to IE8**
$element.get(0).getAttribute("required") returns "" when the required attribute is missing, this causes ALL fields to be required

**In IE10 in compatibility to IE7**
$element.get(0).getAttribute("required") returns null in all cases.
so you can't use required as an attribute on the element

The plugin Author doesn't plan to handle compatibility views as users shouldn't encounter it, but developers that just want to check something in old IE might want to

Comment: This is why "compatibility mode" is not typically used for full website testing... it's not a very good emulator.  [MS knows this and provides various free VPC images containing each IE version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575).

Comment: you are right, but compatibility modes behaves 99% of the time the same as the real thing, and during development it is more convenient then firing up a VM. In this case the bug causes the form to be unusable and gets in the way of other tests

Comment: AFAIK, compatibility mode was originally intended for testing layouts and CSS, not JavaScript.  Anyway, Explorer is flaky enough on its own, so I figure I save time by checking in the real browsers first.

Comment: and you can't check CSS if the page doesn't render because of bugs in javascript.. i hardly check in real VMs as the CSS behaves almost the same and i'm using jQuery to avoid dom api quirks, and rarely i get kicked like this time

Comment: I hear ya.  I avoid IE entirely until the very last minute... make sure the code is compliant, fire up VPC and test.

Comment: This appears to no longer be an issue with IE KB2829530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In IE10 in compatibility to IE8**
element.attributes["required"] is null if the required attribute is missing

**In IE10 in compatibility to IE7**
element.attributes["required"].value returns "-1" if  required attribute exists and "null" otherwise

so updated my fork to the jQuery validate plugin for this fix
all details here
https://github.com/avipinto/jquery-validation/commit/a22d4c37c3047199bf17a4943e3be352d88d8158

Answer (score 0):

I changed mine to call

$element.get(0).hasAttribute("required")

before checking the value with getAttribute()

Comment: getAttribute works in In IE10 in compatibility to IE8 but fails at In IE10 in compatibility to IE7 - throws an error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'hasAttribute'"