# IE10 compatibility mode input type = email/url/number

Tags: validation, input, internet-explorer-10

With older IE (IE8, IE7) you could use modern input types (email, url, number etc) and use a JS poly-fill to implement HTML5 like form validation.

With IE10 compatibility mode, these email / url input types revert back to type="text", causing issues with these poly-fills

HTML:

```
<input type="email" id="test1" />
<input type="url" id="test2" />
<input type="text" id="test3" />
```

JS:

```
// IE7, IE8, IE8 compatibility mode this will be "email"    
console.log($("#test1").attr("type"));

//IE10 standards, IE10 compatibility (7,8,9), this will be "text"
console.log($("#test1").attr("type"));
```

There's similar issues with the required attribute. You can get around that by analyzing the .attributes property (in IE10 Compat mode, two required attributes show up, one a string and one an int), e.g:

```
function check(el){

    var req, type, attr,
    attrs = el.attributes;

    for (var i = 0, l = attrs.length; i < l; i++) {
        attr = attrs.item(i);
        if (attr.nodeName === "required" || attr.nodeName === "type") {

            console.log("name  : " + attr.nodeName);
            console.log("value : " + attr.nodeValue);
            console.log("type of nodeValue: " + (typeof attr.nodeValue));

        }
    }
}
```

But no luck with the type attribute being duplicated and showing the intended value. Is compatibility mode just fubar?  Please no suggestions on how to force IE into standards mode. The document mode is controlled via HTTP headers inside our (large) company.

Answer (score 2):

This prior [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080731/jquery-validate-bug-with-required-validation-on-ie10-in-compatibility-mode-to-ie) seems to have the info you seek.  Note the second answer in particular provides a forked jQuery validate plugin that looks to compensate for the known issue.

Comment: That only relates to required fields. That issue is easy enough to solve. The issue outlined aboveis regarding input types

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `data-type` on the same tag with the same value, compare it to the computed value at runtime, then override if differing after load.  Then after that, load the polyfill.

Comment: Doing something similar to that, unfortunately.