# JQuery Form Validation not working in IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form using **jquery validate** with **PHP** but 
when i am  using IE browser but the script is not wotking in IE

**Here is my code:**

```
$("#enrollform").validate({
rules: {
   fname_name: {
       required: true,
       lettersonly: true,
       minlength: 2,
       maxlength: 25
   },
},
messages: {
   fname_name: {
       required: "Please Enter First Name",
       lettersonly: "Please Enter Only Letters"
   },
});
```

Comment: please show what code you have tried...

Comment: $("#enrollform").validate({
                rules: { 
     fname_name: {
      required: true,
      lettersonly: true,
      minlength: 2,
                        maxlength: 25
     },
  },
       messages: { 
   fname_name:{
       required: "Please Enter First Name",  
    lettersonly: "Please Enter Only Letters"  
  }, 
  });

Comment: JavaScript does not care about your framework... only the rendered code in the browser.   **Show us the relevant HTML markup for your form.**

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing curly bracket `}`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#enrollform").validate({
    rules: {
     fname_name: {
      required: true,
      lettersonly: true,
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 25
     }, <---unnecessary, remove this
    },
    messages: {
     fname_name: {
      required: "Please Enter First Name",
      lettersonly: "Please Enter Only Letters"
     }, <---unnecessary, remove this
    } //<--- missed this bracket
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<form role="form" id="enrollform">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="fname_name">FirstName:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname_name" name="fname_name">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Possible causes validation not working in IE

- unnecessary commas
- [jQuery validate bug with required validation on IE10 in compatibility mode to IE7/IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080731/jquery-validate-bug-with-required-validation-on-ie10-in-compatibility-mode-to-ie)

In 2nd case scenario [here is the fix](https://github.com/avipinto/jquery-validation/commit/efd7daf95eb5ed4acf44cd5523e0a23ab88c2a9d)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0pk7pk4/9/)

Comment: I am using below code but not working $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enrollform").validate({
       rules: {
        fname_name: {
         required: true,
         lettersonly: true,
         minlength: 2,
         maxlength: 25
        },
       },
       messages: {
        fname_name: {
         required: "Please Enter First Name",
         lettersonly: "Please Enter Only Letters"
        },
       } //<--- missed this bracket
    });
   });

Comment: <form id="enrollform" method="post" action="#" name="enrollform">
    <div style="float: left;width:400px;">
    <div class="fieldgroup">
     <label for="user_login">First Name :</label>
     <input type="text" name="fname_name" required /> 
    </div><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Submit " style="width: 100px;">
    </div>
   </form>

Comment: open this page in IE and tell me its working or not http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/ievalidation.php

Comment: Above link not working in IE there no validation message

Comment: give it one more shot